# Connecting existing data folder in fresh installation

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.0

I had to reinstall Postgres x64 9.0.18 on Windows 7 from scratch and I have a full copy of the old data folder. How can I weave the existing database folder into the fresh installation of Pg 9.0.18? When I install over the same directory structure, the install routine recognizes the old data folder but claims that it doesn't contain proper database data. I also tried to start the postgres service with a different data directory (pointing -D to the copy of /data), but it won't start. Can I somehow edit or patch something in order to access my old database? In former versions there was a pg_databases file.

Comment: Are you *certain* the old datadir is from 9.0.x? Check the `PG_VERSION` file (but make certain not to edit/save it). Are you pointing it at the datadir containing directories like `pg_xlog`, `global`, `base`, `pg_clog`, etc? Is there any chance you left out "unimportant" folders? When you use `pg_ctl` to try to start it with the old datadir and it "won't start" what exactly happens, what're the errors, what's the log output?

Comment: Thank you for addressing my issue. PG_VERSION contains 9.0.<LF> My 'backup' folder contains /global and /base, as well as PG_Version, pg_hba.conf, pg_ident.conf, postgresql.conf and postmaster.opts. The other directories that are being created by the current install program (and that are initially either empty or contain a 0000 file) are not included in my saved folder.

Comment: To start with a different data directory, I change the -D path in HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\services\postgresql-x64-9.0\ImagePath and start using services.msc. The error message is Error 1053: Service doesn't reply in time to start or stop command (translated from german). When starting from the cmd, the error message is 1063

Comment: It sounds like your backup is incomplete. If you are missing `pg_clog` in particular that's a real problem. Try starting using `pg_ctl` from the command prompt though. Details about problems should be in the `pg_log` directory.

Comment: by chance I found another backup including pg_clog and all the other folders too. Now the server starts, but I can't access my old database files. Connection is fine if starting with the new, empty data directory, but as soon as I point to my backup dir, pgadmin tells me after entering the password, that the authentication failed. I 'net user postgres' reset the password and copied the new pg_hba.conf to the backup folder. postgresql.conf listens on '*', and file in pg_log says that the password authentication failed